# Windows 7 network drive to Linux filesystem via PuTTY

Tags: windows-7, mapping, network-share

I'm trying to establish a remote ssh connection to a Linux filesystem from Windows 7.

The purpose is to be able to enable Windows programs (like OneNote) to write files to the Linux box, so they can be stored there instead of on the local machine.

So I used [this stackoverflow question](https://web.archive.org/web/20101030145504/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/186968/map-ssh-drive-in-windows) which leads me to [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20180217053422/http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk:80/user/jp107/xp-remote/ssh-map/) since I am using PuTTY to establish the SSH connection.

A few things stick out at me in that tutorial however.

1)  He seems to be connecting to the server on port 22:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cam.ac.uk](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/jp107/xp-remote/ssh-map/puttysession.png))</sub>

But in the 2 pictures before that, he has **destination port 139** on his server

[image]
<sub>(source: [cam.ac.uk](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/jp107/xp-remote/ssh-map/puttytun.png))</sub>

Is that wrong?  To get any response out of my server at all, I leave **tunnel source** port 139, and set **tunnel destination** port **22**, not 139.

2)  The main problem I encounter after establishing the SSH connection (a normal putty window opens, and I log in with my Linux username/pass), is with attempting to map the network drive.

Really I don't know what the 2nd name means (after `\\127.0.0.1\WHATISTHIS`) in

[image]

I thought connecting to `\\127.0.0.1\foldername` was the deal, but it appears no.

Also shouldn't I specify `\\127.0.0.1:139` to make sure it goes to the SSH tunnel?

3)  Finally I find even if I do manage to apparently hit the server at `\\127.0.0.1\`, it doesn't recognize any of the login credentials that I could possibly have set up

[image]

Credentials for the Windows machine don't work, credentials for the Linux box don't work.

Comment: Do you have Samba running on your Linux server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows7 - “The specified network password is not correct.” when the password is in fact correct.](http://serverfault.com/questions/91797/windows7-the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct-when-the-password-is)

Comment: @Chris S That question is good.  Thanks for the link.  Can someone tell me if what I've done above (with the port 22 / 139 part) is correct, so I can eliminate that as a possible part of the problem?

Comment: @bobo, if it's asking for credentials then you've got the port forwarding correct. If that wasn't correct, it would simply state that the server can not be reached (or something similar).

Comment: I don't know what Samba is, and a cursory Google image search indicates I could definitely use one of those (search with caution). But it appears that's part of the problem.  See my [next question](http://serverfault.com/questions/260270/map-network-drive-field-meanings)?

Comment: Completely close putty, and attempt to connect to \\127.0.0.1, see if that tells you something useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered alternatives to PuTTY? See [my answer to a related question on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/267866/windows-file-system-explorer-ssh-plugin):

> A quick search for "windows sshfs" turned up [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) and [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows).
>
> I have never tried Dokan, but it appears to be a one-man open source project.
>
> ExpanDrive is a commercial product, going for $39.95 at this writing. I installed the 30-day free trial, and it has worked really well. I mounted one of my servers over SSH and it looks and acts like any other network drive.

Comment: +1 for ExpanDrive (I use it and love it).

Comment: -1 I don't have any money right now