# Map Network Drive field meanings

Tags: windows-7, network-share

So I'm continuing to attempt to set up a [Network Drive that will write to a Linux box in the sky](https://serverfault.com/questions/259693/windows-7-network-drive-to-linux-filesystem-via-putty).

I made the NTLM change suggested by [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/91797/windows7-the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct-when-the-password-is), but I still can't understand a few things to do with the original question.

1)  The first is, __what does using `\\127.0.0.1\` as the network folder mean?  If I set up the port 139 forward to tunnel to port 22 on an SSH connection, that means the network drive should "point to the SSH connection", is that right?

2)  So assuming that PuTTY maintains the SSH connection, and the Windows Network Drive is mapped to that SSH connection, **what can the network drive do** with that connection?  Are file reads and writes going to be automatically converted to `wget` or something?

Comment: How is this a professional system administration question?

Comment: Fits in site's tagging system

Comment: The tags are irrelevant.  You seem to be an end-user asking an end-user question which means your question is probably more appropriate for superuser not here.  A professional sysadmin would almost certainly know that a) a SMB server is required on the remote end b) that the output of netstat would show that putty was not bound to the port, and c) Windows has almost certainly already bound the SERVER service to the port 139 on the local system and putty is failing to allocate the port, and that \\127.0.0.1 actually __IS__ your local computer and is not being forwarded at all.

Comment: http://www.blisstonia.com/eolson/notes/smboverssh.php

Comment: @bobobobo - this is your third question in a row that have been closed due to them being in appropriate for a professional sysadmin site. If you continue to ignore the FAQ your account will be temporarily suspended.

Comment: http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/CifsOverSSH/VistaLoopback.html

Answer (score 2):

1. The location `\\127.0.0.1\` means open the SMB root folder on the local computer. SMB communicates over port 139; Putty is listening on Port 139 on the local computer, it takes that traffic and sends it over it's SSH Tunnel (running on Port 22 by default) to the remote destination of the Tunnel. The remote destination is a Linux server running Samba which communicates via SMB.
2. The Tunnel doesn't translate anything at all, it's just shipping the data to the remote end. The server at the remote end speaks the same protocol. The Tunnel is just allowing you to connect to a remote network, very similar to a VPN.

Comment: So how do you make sure Samba "picks up" the connection at the other end, and not the Command Terminal `bash`?

Comment: Perhaps its port 139 that does it.  Samba must be on port 139.  What goes in the [login dialog box](http://i.imgur.com/3xNQW.png), my Samba user/pass? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The Tunnel specifies where the connection goes. In the putty configuration, you specify the Source Port (the Localhost [aka 127.0.0.1] is implied); then you specified the Destination, which should be the name or IP of the remote computer and the Port 139, which is where Samba will be listening for the connection.